# Ajax infinite scroll not working after filter product magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

This my product listing page.
http://45.56.70.30/pospaper/full-catalog/inkjet-cartridges.html

I have installed lof_ajaxscroll extension.when page loads first time then ajax infinite scroll working smoother.

When I click on any attribute like (Brother) then infinite scroll stops working.

This is my layered navigation js file code.

```
function callAjax(url)
{
    ajaxcall = true;
    $(".wk_layer_loader_bg").show();
    $.ajax({
        url     :   url,
        type    :   "GET",
        success :   function (data) {
            var body;
            var dom = document.createElement("html");
            dom.innerHTML = data;
            if ($(window).width() >=750) {
                if (($(data).find('.columns').length>0)) {
                    body = $(".columns", dom);
                    $(".columns").html(body.html());
                    $(".wk_layer_loader_bg").hide();
                } else {
                    $(".wk_layer_loader_bg").hide();
                    body = $("#maincontent", dom);
                    $("#maincontent").html(body.html());
                }
            } else {
                if (($(data).find('.columns').length>0)) {
                    body = $(".columns", dom);
                    $(".columns").html(body.html());
                    $(".wk_layer_loader_bg").hide();
                } else {
                    body = $("#maincontent", dom);
                    $("#maincontent").html(body.html());
                    $(".wk_layer_loader_bg").hide();
                }
            }
            $('[class=filter-options-content]').each(function () {
                $(this).css('display','none');
            });
            $(".attr_filter_input").trigger('keyup');
            window.history.pushState("object", "current title", url);
            location.reload();
        }
    })
}
```

Currently I am using `location.reload()` function.

This is my ajax infinite scroll file path.
http://45.56.70.30/pospaper/pub/static/frontend/Pospaper/theme/en_US/Lof_AjaxScroll/js/script.js

So which function I need to use for ajax infinite scroll after select an attribute.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you fixed this?

Comment: No i have temporary add the location.reload() function.Because once the page loads then infinite scroll works.But i want use infinite scroll with ajax.

Comment: @MackieeE did you get any idea?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Comment: Which extensions you are using for infinite scroll and layered navigation? There is an extension available in the GIT.Find for this extension Stratergy_Infintescroll. This extension is working fine for me.Please let me know is this working or not? Thanks!

Comment: I have installed Stratergy_Infintescroll but it is not working any other suggestion pls ?

Comment: Can you please send me your url?